# Fate of Clara Oswald after she went to Gallifrey

Tags: doctor-who

Why did Clara Oswald go to Gallifrey? She stated that she hates it very much, so why?

Also is there any info about her fate after this episode?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The last time we saw Clara in *Hell Bent* she was setting off in another stolen TARDIS with Ashilda/Me. Clara had been rescued from death by The Doctor, but she knew that her death was a 'fixed point' and had to happen - the universe depends on fixed points in time not being changed. She intended to return to Gallifrey so that the Time Lords could reinsert her into her own timeline and effectively die.

However, they talk about returning to Gallifrey "the long way around". This strongly suggests that they are going to explore the universe and were in no hurry to return to Gallifrey. Me cannot die. Clara was in a state where she also could not die. Exploring infinity seems a good way for them to pass the time.

We have to assume that Clara eventually returned to Gallifrey and died. In *Twice Upon A Time*, the Testimony Foundation returned to the Doctor the memories of Clara that had been taken from him. As The Testimony collected a person's memories at the point of their death, they would only have been able to do this if Clara had died.

Due to the time-travelling nature of the show, it could be possible for Clara to return to the series from whatever time passed between her leaving with Me and her eventual death.

Comment: The last time we saw her was right before the 12th Doctor's regeneration, although it's not clear if he was just hallucinating like 11 did with Amy, also before regenerating.

Comment: @tilley31 Clara was wiped from The Doctor's memory after the events of *Hell Bent*. The vision of Clara was his memories returned.

Comment: That's a good interpretation, hadn't think about it like that. Out of Universe, they can always use her character in a future episode...maybe even a 60th anniversary special or something like that.

Comment: Clara had died. The Testimony could have collected her in the trap street the instant before (or indeed after) the Doctor scooped her out.